# Latex/Asymptote to Image for Website?

Tags: javascript, image, math, latex

I'm working on a database of math problems right now - all the problems are formatted in LaTeX, but there are [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/index.html#dir) images as well.

It doesn't look like Mathjax supports Asymptote - what would be the best way to get the images from each math problem? How does [Art of Problem Solving's TeXeR](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php) get Asymptote?

Could we send the code and render the image client-side, or should we extract the asy code for each problem, get an image, save these images to the database, and link each image to its respective problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late here, but I'll suggest something anyway.

What I would do is simply render all the images serverside. You can have Asymptote rerender images if there are any changes to the original file.

That way you save bandwidth and processing time for the client a lot. You may have a lot more data to store, but this way you'd also have a bit more control over the pics.

Asymptote lets you define the output, that way you can have Your server automatically create them based completely on the original problem, name them accordingly. That way they are already 'linked'.

This is probably the best answer I can give without code.